# Debugging code in C for figuring out length of number?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while, cs50

So, I'm working on a code in C that would be used to figure out the length of a given number. I know the right way now to figure it out. However, I do not understand why my original code below was wrong. Can someone help me debug it?

Edit: I was also wondering why the parameter in while is supposed to be "dgts != 0" or "dgts > 0" ? Like, can you explain what this means and why it makes sense?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int lngth (int dgts);

int main(void){
    int num = get_long_long();
    int length = lngth(num);
    printf("%i",length);
}
int lngth (int dgts){
    int cnt = 0;
    int y = dgts;
    while (dgts !=0 ){
        y = y/10;
         cnt ++;
        printf("%i\n",cnt);
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: The length depends on encoding. `99` can be presented as `ninety nine`. Both express the same knowledge, one is of the length 2 the other is 11.

Comment: `while (dgts !=0 ){
        y = y/10;` you're not changing `dgts` so infinite loop here, should be `while (y){
        y /= 10;`

Comment: [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) can help a great deal.

Comment: While the solution to your problem has been given, I would still recommend you learn to make use of a debugger such as GDB to step through your code.

Comment: I tried to compile your code, but `get_long_long` is undefined, and anyway I can't see how `int num = get_long_long();` makes any sense.

Comment: Actually, I'm also a little worried about the `int num = get_long_long();` line.  A `long long` can hold values greater than that of an `int`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks so much! I was also wondering why does adding just 'y' instead of 'y > 0' works as well?

Comment: If you want to know the number of digits of a number given a base, use the [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) function: [man 3 log](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/log.3.html)

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh sorry...it's a function thru CS50's database...so I'm using it for one of the psets

Comment: `while(y)` is like `while(y!=0)` not like `while(y>0)` if `y` can be negative

Comment: and okay i'll look into GDB. thanks! @ChristianGibbons

Comment: So where is the CS50 `#include "cs50.h"` header?

Comment: ooh okay makes sense thanks! sorry one last thing, I was also wondering why the parameter in while is supposed to be "y != 0" or "y > 0" in the first place? Like, can you explain what this means and why it makes sense? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: the main point is to test against zero. While it's _not_ zero then you have to keep on dividing to count the digits

Comment: @DeborahA try to formalise the steps you perform mathematically, then it becomes obvious why it's `!= 0`. Programming is not about "to do X I need to apply the template Y", it is simply decomposing a larger problem to a smaller tasks, then evaluating them one after another.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre oh but then will would a number ever get zero ... i understand it can approach zero but it won't ever actually reach it..so does the programming software just assumes there's nothing to divide anymore when the number is pretty small?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and with that explanation it becomes obvious that `0` is an edge case as well (and is not addressed in the solution).

Comment: @DeborahA when you divide an integer by an integer the result is an integer as well, it's truncated. `9 / 10 == 0`

Comment: Use `snprintf`.  This will return the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jean-François Fabre in the comments, you created an infinite loop in your `int lngth (int dgts)` function:

```
    while (dgts !=0 ){
        y = y/10;
        ...
    }
```

Because the conditional `dgts != 0` relies on dgts rather than `y`, and `y` is the one changing at `y = y/10`, the loop will never complete.

Answer (score 0):

Code has 2 problems:

1. The infinite loop of `while (dgts !=0 ){ y = y/10; cnt ++; }` `dgts` never changes, so once code enters the loop it is stuck there.  [@Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014956/debugging-code-in-c-for-figuring-out-length-of-number/48015299#comment82998950_48014956)
2. Questionable arrangement when `dgts == 0` as that is usually though of as a one digit number and not a no digit number.  A `do` loop is a simple solution.

Repaired code:

```
int lngth(int dgts) {
  int cnt = 0;
  do {
    cnt++;
    printf("%i\n", cnt);
    dgts /= 10; 
  } while (dgts);  // while dgts is non-zero
  return cnt;
}
```

---

*length of a given number* is working on the idea of the number of decimal digits.  If the length includes a `'-'` for negative numbers then only a small changed needed.

```
  // int cnt = 0;
  int cnt = dgts < 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the condition of the while loop

```
while (dgts !=0 ){
       ^^^^^^^^
```

I think that you mean

```
while (y !=0 ){
       ^^^^^
```

But in any case the function is wrong because its parameter can be equal to `0` and `0` is a valid number that contains one digit.

Also it does not make sense to define the return type as `int` because the length of a number can not be a negative value.

The function can look like

```
unsigned int lngth ( int dgts )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    unsigned int cnt = 0;

    do
    {
        ++cnt;
    } while ( dgts /= Base );


    return cnt;
}
```

And in main you should write

```
unsigned int length = lngth(num);
printf("%u\n", length );
```

Also take into account that it seems the function `get_long_long` returns an integer of the type `long long int`.

If so then you should write

```
long long int num = get_long_long();
```

And in this case the function should be declared

```
unsigned int lngth ( long long int dgts );
```

Pay attention to that there is no reason to declare identifiers like `dgts` or `lngth`. Use complete words. For example

```
unsigned int length ( long long int number );
             ^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^
```

Or just

```
unsigned int length ( long long int n );
             ^^^^^^                ^^^
```